Why is edit not working react-admin with custom dataProvider
I am using react-admin library
The thing is I am not sure what's the issue, but the edit button does not work.
I tried
User list component
import {List, Datagrid, TextField, EditButton, DeleteButton} from 'react-admin'
const UserList = (props) => {
    console.log(props)
  return (
    <List {...props}>
        <Datagrid   >
            <TextField source='id'/>
            <TextField source='name'/>
            <TextField source='email'/>
            <TextField label='Deptartment' source='company.bs'/>
            <EditButton basepath='/users'/>
            <DeleteButton  basepath='/users'/>
        </Datagrid>
    </List>
  )

my component:
import { dataProvider } from '../helpers/usersDataProvider'
import UserCreate from './UserCreate'
const UsersManagement = () => {
  return (
    <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider}>
        <Resource name='users' list={UserList} create={UserCreate}/>
    </Admin>
  )


custom dataProvider:
const API_URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com";

export const dataProvider = {
  getList: async (resource, params) => {
   //normal fetch func
  },
  update: async (resource, params) => {
    const response = await fetchUtils.fetchJson(
      `${API_URL}/${resource}/${params.id}`,{
        headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
          },
      },
      {
        method: "PUT",
        body: JSON.stringify(params.data),
      },
      
    );
    return { data: response.json };
  },
  delete: async (resource, params) => {
    const response = await fetchUtils.fetchJson(
      `${API_URL}/${resource}/${params.id}`,
      {
        method: "DELETE",
      }
    );
    return { data: response.json };
  },
};

It should show an edit view, but It calls getList function. The delete button excutes properly, I am just having issues with editButton

How is the JSON you receive looking alike? Can you provide an example?

You must create an Edit form and connect it in your <Resource name='users' edit= ...>
